# meaning of 'time on a goat'

Tags: meaning

> Detective A: (The Victim said) speeding through Times Square after six? (And She's lying.)
>
> Detective B: You'd make better ***time on a goat***.

I know 'goat time' means 'good time', but I don't know how I understand 'time on a goat'.

Maybe the victim is lying, so you'd better no waste your time on her?
Or it just means that you can't drive fast through Times Square after six?

Please help me to understand it perfectly!

Comment: Why do you think 'goat time' means 'good time'?

Comment: You would be quicker if you rode a goat through Times Square after six. (Because of the traffic.) No way were they 'speeding'.

Comment: I think we need a better clue. Can you tell us where you heard this?

Comment: It could equally well have been Detective B: You'd make better time on an ostrich. Hard finding one in NYC, but that's what would take the time. I remember Harpo riding one rather fast. // 'on a goat/horse/tram/bus etc' means '[if you were] riding [on] a goat /horse...'. Wrongly parsed; it should be [make (better time)] [on a goat].

Comment: @NigelJ It makes sense! Thank you so much!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you so much! It helped a lot!

Comment: +q for asking an intelligent question that has 'goat' in the title

Comment: @EdwinAshworth How much goat time does it take to shoot an elephant in your pajamas?

Comment: @Barmar I suppose we're allowed capricious comments as it's the festive season.

Comment: People have imaginations. Not everything is pre-written or pre-said. Not everything is a pre-existing expression. That said the question is wrong: it is not time on a goat. It's: to make better time on a [goat]. You might want to correct your question.

Comment: I'm voting to close: this question is based on a misunderstanding of standard English, & lack of research on what "make better time" means. "You'd make better time [by the stated method]" means "you would arrive earlier [if you used the stated method]"; the method here is "on a goat", which is used as an example of a slow and unconventional way to travel. "Goat time" is a red herring (a further misunderstanding by the OP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Make better time" means "travel faster," so the sentence means, "You'd travel faster on a goat" (in other words, "You'd travel faster if you were riding a goat").

Just as you guessed, Detective B is saying that you can't drive fast through Times Square after six.

Answer (score -3):

I did some research and “goat time” isn’t a saying nor is “time in the goat”, so it’s probably a riddle.

Comment: No; as already explained, 'You'd make better time on a goat' = 'You'd make better time if you were [doing something as crazy as] riding on a goat [/ turtle / aardvark / penguin ...]'.

Comment: Okay what dictionary did you find goat time?

Comment: This answer misunderstands the question, which itself misunderstands the sentence. "You'd make better time [by the stated method]" means "you would arrive earlier [if you used the stated method]"; the method here is "on a goat", which is used as an example of a slow and unconventional way to travel. "Goat time" is a red herring (a further misunderstanding by the OP). There's no riddle here, just a poor question and an answer that fails to address it.